# Creating custom editor fields based on presence of custom attribute

Tags: unity, code-reflection

I'm creating a manager object that controls a bunch of other objects at once.

I want to be able to restrict / expose parameters in the target object to the manager via a custom attribute. I have the following working:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class ManagableAttribute : Attribute {}

public class TargetObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    // public ObjectScript obj;
    
    [Managable]public float var1;
    public float var2;
}
```

Two variables in the target object, only one of which has the `[Managable]` attribute.

Based on some other posts I found, in the editor script I have it searching the fields in the target script and identifying the ones with the `[Managable]` attribute and printing them to the terminal:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(TargetObject))]
[CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class ObjectManagerEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        TargetObject targetObject =  (TargetObject)target;

        //// Manually creating the variable floatfield i need
        //o.var1 = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("var1", o.var1);

        Type targetType = targetObject.GetType();
        FieldInfo[] objectFields = targetType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

        foreach (var field in objectFields)
        {
            ManagableAttribute thisAttribute = (ManagableAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(ManagableAttribute));
            if (thisAttribute != null)
            {
                // Debug.Log(thisAttribute);
                var f = field;
                Debug.Log(field.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can I have it create an `EditorGUILayout.FloatField` (or whatever type) in the loop for each variable it finds with the `[Managable]` attribute?

Comment: What have you tried to do to add an editor field for each of the fields you've found?

Comment: var f = field.GetValue(targetObject);
                
f = EditorGUILayout.FloatField("test", f);


I can't seem to work out how to access the actual instance of the field on the target object via reflection in a way that I can attach to the editor field.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling there's a better way but this seems to work

```
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {   
        FieldInfo[] objectFields = targetType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

        foreach (var field in objectFields)
        {
            ManagableAttribute thisAttribute = (ManagableAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(ManagableAttribute));
            if (thisAttribute != null)
            {
                float tempValue = EditorGUILayout.FloatField(field.Name, (float) field.GetValue(targetObject));
                field.SetValue(targetObject, tempValue);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might want to use SerializedProperties instead, to get proper support for undo, save/load, multi-object editing, etc. Making direct changes to the raw C# object without going through the Unity infrastructure can cause them to escape the editor's notice, so it doesn't know to serialize them into your scene file.

Comment: That's great info thanks.